# Does Method.hashCode() consider the method's parameter types?

Tags: java, reflection, hashcode

The Javadocs say:

> Returns a hashcode for this Method. The hashcode is computed as the exclusive-or of the hashcodes for the underlying method's declaring class name and the method's name.

Conspicuously absent from this description are the types of the Method's parameter types - does this mean that two methods on the same class with the same name, but different parameters, would have the same `hashCode()`?

Comment: Yeah, but not sure I want to rely on undocumented behavior...  I'm downloading the JDK source code now.

Comment: Just a quick sidenote: Never, ever try to deduce from o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()  -->  o1.equals(o2);   Hashcodes are not IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - methods with the same name and the same declaring class have, as documented, the same hash-code. Which, I agree, is a bit counter-intuitive.

The code in Sun's JDK:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return getDeclaringClass().getName().hashCode() ^ getName().hashCode();
}
```

But `hashCode()` isn't a sign for equality. The `equals(..)` method takes into account arguments.

Comment: Indeed, if I hadn't read the Javadocs closely this would have made for a nasty bug, very tough to track down :-/

Comment: @sanity: If some piece of your program really relied on the fact that different objects must have different hash codes, **this is the bug**.

Comment: @Paulo: Its only a bug if you don't account for the possibility of a hash collision in the design of your code, which I do.

Comment: @sanity hash collisions are always a possibility, even if arguments are included. And they are resolved by using the `equals(..)` method. If you overload a method 2 or 3 times, this will mean the hashtable lookup will take 4, rather than 1 operation (regardless of the map size)

Comment: Every beginner java book tells you that hashcodes must be equal if the objects are equal. It also says that collisions are perfectly fine, as long as you obey the rule above. The only thing a hash says about equality is that non-equal objects have different hashes (as long as you followed the hashcode/equals contract).

Comment: @bozho, yes - I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see

```
Method[] ms = String.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : ms) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    System.out.println(method.hashCode());
}
```

compareTo
-319450075

compareTo
-319450075

indexOf
887779372

indexOf
887779372

indexOf
887779372

indexOf
887779372
...

Comment: Yup, I just read the JDK source code, it ignores the parameter types.  Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem. Note that the equals/hashCode contract is still preserved, in that two Methods that compare favorably with equals() will have the same hashCode.

Comment: The equals/hashCode contract is preserved, but I think there is a general assumption that hashCode() "tries" to be different in the case that two objects aren't equal.

Comment: From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29 : "However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables."